# where put a batch programm to use it with matlab?

Tags: bash, matlab

(Ubuntu 16.04)
Someone gave me a batch file to use a program in command line. So I put it in a folder and create an aliase to be able to use it everywhere (and it works).

But now, I want to run this program from Matlab. So I tried

```
system('bhsim command line');
```

and obtained this error :

```
/bin/bash: bhsim : commande introuvable
```

bhsim is the name of the program I want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (at least) to solution :

The first is giving the full path (skr's answer)

```
system('/path/bhsim command line');
```

The second is : add the path to $PATH. On Ubuntu :

(in the terminal)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bhsim/
```

and then you can use

```
system('bhsim command line');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PATH environment variable issue.

Try giving full path

```
system('/path/bhsim command line');
```

Comment: It works but is there another way ? Write the all path is not very "friendly"... I tried to add the path in matlab `addpath /home/.../` but it doesn't run

Comment: you can copy 'bhsim' to standard location /usr/bin. then you can use the old method 'system('bhsim command line');' or update the PATH variable with bhsim location in .bashrc file.